# Water Meter Monitoring

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, optoelectronics

Working on a project where I am wanting to monitor water meter via a magnetic sensor which will detect the spinning magnetic disc. It's very similar to the project this person has accomplished:

http://www.edcheung.com/automa/water.htm

My issue is that my water meter is about 200 feet towards the street. So my plan would be to put the sensor and op-amp in the meter "pit" and then send the pulses back to the pulse counter back at the house. This would be done for two meters (one irrigation and one normal potable water).

My question is will the voltage drop of the 5v output of the op-amp be enough after 200ft of 18AWG irrigation cable which I plan to use?

My plan was to send send 12V down to the meter and use a 7805 to power things down there, or again will the 5V over 200ft be OK?

What about lightening protection? How can I minimize those issues? Would some optoisolator make sense or would that really not offer any protection?

I'm open to other suggestions including the use of a micro controller at the meter "pit", but I think the op-amp is the simplest solution.

In Ed's example he has a variable resistor for the 2V reference, I might want to use some reference IC for that since mine will be exposed to more environmental conditions.

EDIT:

What about some other solutions? Wireless transmitting of the pulse? This way only need to send power down to the meter?

What about some type of fiber solution? The electronics in the meter box pulsing a light?

Given that it seems that the voltage drop will not be a big concern, my biggest concern now is the protection of the devices. I would plan to hook this up to a 1-wire Counter chip and then have a 1-wire <-> Ethernet gateway on the network. My concern is exposing the network and all other equipment to lightning damage via the 1-wire network which will consist of 200ft to one meter, and then 250ft to another meter, all in the ground in Florida.

What about using Shielded Cat5e cable?

Answer (score 3):

## Voltage Drops

Pulse counter has a high impedance input (probably).  So, there will be practically no current through the signal wire.  Therefore there will be no voltage drop across the signal wire.

I'm assuming that you're planning to make a 4-terminal system (power, GND, irrigation signal, potable signal).  At the house, your signal will be measured with respect to, GND.  Voltage drop across the GND wire will be added to the signal (as a DC offset).  Power supply current is running through GND wire.  We can't assume that this current will be negligible.  You should measure it.  Resistance of 18AWG wire is 6.4 Ohm per 1000ft ([from tables](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)).  If the circuitry at the end of 200ft wire consumes 100mA (for example), it will cause a 0.128V drop in the GND line.

Your pulse signal is a pseudo-digital voltage signal.  To an extent, it's tolerant to voltage drops across the signal and ground wires.  As long as the pulse signal is greater than a threshold, the counter will count it.

## Interference

For a 200ft line interference can become a serious problem.  Usually, the strongest source of interference is 60Hz from AC power lines.  If you hang your cable it along the power lines, it would be the worst case.  Cable with properly grounding shield helps.  Some signaling methods are less susceptible: 4-20mA current loop, differential signaling. For the time being, I will not go into more details here.

## Lightning Protection

Gas Discharge Tube (GDT) or Spark Gaps.

Optoisolator makes sense.  Keep in mind that power supply and GND lines are also susceptible to lightning.  To isolate the the exposed part of your circuit completely, use an isolated power supply.

Comment: better signal wires were twisted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Ok, so the voltage drop should not be an issue. The wire will be in the ground and I will have to cross the buried main feed to the house, but not run parallel to it. 

If I were to just a shielded cable, I would just ground the shield at both sides?

What about using twisted pair wire? What is benefit there?